# unable to generate images - permissions are ok

Tags: media

I tried everything and set all folders in files to 777. But I can't generate images. 
I work with Drupal 7 and php 5.5.5 as fast-cgi.

Any idea?

Comment: "Tried everything" and "can't generate images" really doesn't say anything. Do you have GD or ImageMagick installed and working?

Comment: Also post here any error logs that appeared in Drupal/server logs during file uploads.

Comment: What images are you referring to? Image style derivative images or something else? Do you have any errors in your watchdog log or server log?